# Force django to use one of two foreign keys

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model with two foreign keys on another one. 
DB structure:

```
class LightUsers(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, related_name="lightuser_admin")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, related_name="lightuser_user")

class User(models.Model):
    ...
```

I want to perform query like:

```
SELECT * FROM lightusers INNER JOIN user ON (lightusers.admin_id = user.id) WHERE lightusers.user_id IN ( 1, 2, 3)
```

To achieve this I wrote next code:

```
light_users = LightUsers.objects.filter(user__in=[1,2,3]).select_related('user')
```

But Django translates this code in query with join by another foreign key field. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM lightusers INNER JOIN user ON (lightusers.user_id = user.id) WHERE lightusers.user_id IN ( 1, 2, 3)
```

Is there a way to force Django use Foreign Key that I want. Or raw query is the only option?

Comment: what is the condition that triggers the use of one field over the other ?

Comment: @karthikr I need to get data from **user** table by ids in **admin** column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end i gave up to make this in one query. And divided it into two:

```
relations = LightUsers.objects.filter(user__in=[1, 2, 3]).values_list('admin_id', 'user_id')
light_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=[relation[0] for relation in relations])
```

And then combined result.

Comment: You can optimize this into one query with a sub-query like this:

`light_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=LightUsers.objects.filter(user__in=[1, 2, 3]).values_list('admin_id', flat=True))`

Comment: Yes, but in this case I'll lose connection between admin and user. Can't track which user relates to which admin =)

Answer (score 2):

> I need to get data from **user** table by ids in **admin** column

IF you want this, then you just have to use the `admin` field:

```
light_users = LightUsers.objects.filter(admin__in=[1,2,3])
```

but that's not the same as:

> I want to perform query like:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM lightusers INNER JOIN user ON (lightusers.admin_id = user.id) WHERE lightusers.user_id IN ( 1, 2, 3)
> ```

This basically means give me all `lightusers` with `user_id` IN ( 1, 2, 3)  and having an `admin`. In an `ORM` fashion this can be achieved like so:

```
light_users = LightUsers.objects.filter(
        user_id__in=[1,2,3], #this will filter lightusers.user_id IN ( 1, 2, 3)
        admin__isnull=False  #this will INNER JOIN users on admin and get row having an admin
    )
```

Comment: `light_users = LightUsers.objects.filter(user__in=[1, 2, 3], admin__isnull=False)` does not join tables. It just adds `AND cw_core_lightusers.admin_id IS NOT NULL`. And after that, when i perform `for light_user in light_users: name = light_user.user.username` this makes query for every element in light_users. And that is axactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: `INNER JOIN user ON (lightusers.admin_id = user.id)` is the same as `lightusers.admin_id IS NOT NULL` in terms of returned `lightusers` (both will only return rows with `admins`. However if you want to actually add the `INNER JOIN` then change it to `admin__id__isnull=False`. But after all this `INNER JOIN` **won't** populate you the `user` field. If you want `user` field populated with `admin` data, you can't do that with the ORM *(except `.raw`)*. But what you can do is `LightUsers.objects.filter(admin__in=[1,2,3]).select_related('admin')` and then use `light_user.admin.username` instead.

Comment: Made it with 2 queries. Thank you for help

Comment: No problem, check how you can merge them into 1 ;)